# How to convert URL-contains Excel formula to Power BI calculated column?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I use this Excel formula to tell if the URL in the A column contains the '/amp/' string:

```
 = IF(OR(SUMPRODUCT(--((ISERR(SEARCH({"/amp/"},a2)))))>0),FALSE,TRUE)))))))))))))
```

How would I do that in a calculated column/measure in Power BI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [FIND](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/find-function-dax) function to search for the `/amp/` in the column where the URL is stored. You can define the value to be returned, if the pattern is not found, but not the value in case it is. So you can use [IF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/if-function-dax) to be able to freely define "contains" and "do not contains" values.

```
=IF(FIND("/amp/", 'TableName'[ColumnWithURL], -1) = -1, <value_if_true>, <value_if_false>)
```

Comment: IsAMP = IF(FIND("/amp/", ABC[Landing Page], 1, -1) = -1, false, true)